# How to draw on collectionView cells using UICollectionView's selectItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I added the repo I am working here:

https://github.com/AlexMarshall12/singleDayTimeline/tree/master/singleDayTimeline

Basically I have 900 collectionView cells (with a custom XIB layout).

```
    let cellIdentifier = "DayCollectionViewCell"
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var dates = [Date?]()
    var startDate: Date?
    @IBOutlet weak var daysCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        daysCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "DayCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        let allDates = Helper.generateRandomDate(daysBack: 900, numberOf: 10)
        self.dates = allDates.sorted(by: {
            $0!.compare($1!) == .orderedAscending
        })
        startDate = self.dates.first! ?? Date()

        daysCollectionView.delegate = self
        daysCollectionView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 900
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = daysCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell

        let cellDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: indexPath.item, to: self.startDate!)

        if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 15 {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
            let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: cellDate!)
            cell.drawMonth(month: monthString)
        }
        if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 1 && Calendar.current.component(.month, from: cellDate!) == 1 {
            print("drawYEAR")
            cell.drawYear(year:Calendar.current.component(.year, from: cellDate!))
        }
        if self.dates.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(cellDate!, inSameDayAs: $0!) }) {
            print("same")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            print("not me")
            //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
        return cell
    }

//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
//                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
//                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//        return CGSize(width: 2, height: daysCollectionView.bounds.size.height/2 )
//    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.dates.count)))
        let randomDate = self.dates[randomIndex]
        let daysFrom = randomDate?.days(from: self.startDate!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: daysFrom!, section: 0)
//        if let cell = daysCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as DayCollectionViewCell? {
//            print("found it")
//        } else {
//            print("didn't find it")
//        }
        daysCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        daysCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
    }
```

Then here is the cell:

```
   class DayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImage: UIImageView!

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            arrowImage.isHidden = !isSelected
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        arrowImage.isHidden = true
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func drawMonth(month: String){

    }
    func drawYear(year: Int){

    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

So the plan is that when that button is pressed, you can see in the @IBAction func buttonPressed that a random date is chosen and scrolled to, then that cell is selected in the collectionView. Then that makes the cell's arrow drawn with `arrowImage.isHidden = !isSelected` in the override var isSelected function.

Currently, this works almost perfectly. The arrow is redrawn under the selected cell EXCEPT when the new index which gets randomly selected is far enough away from the current index. My theory is that if the index difference is big enough, the next cell hasn't been loaded/dequeued yet and thus isSelected is never called. However I am not sure still why its not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Add a reloadCell function to change ui of cell. Then you should remove `override var isSelected` and `arrowImage.isHidden = true` from `awakeFromNib` function.

```
func reloadCell(_ isSelected:Bool){
   arrowImage.isHidden = !isSelected
}
```

2- You should define a variable on `ViewController.swift` class `private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?` and then you should add this code for to check if arrow is hidden or not.

```
 if let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath {
     cell.reloadCell(selectedRow == indexPath)
 } else {
     cell.reloadCell(false)
 }
```

3- And if you change your button action function like this below, it would be worked.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.dates.count)))
    let randomDate = self.dates[randomIndex]
    let daysFrom = randomDate?.days(from: self.startDate!)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: daysFrom!, section: 0)
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    daysCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    daysCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

- All codes here.

`ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit
let cellIdentifier = "DayCollectionViewCell"
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
var dates = [Date?]()
var startDate: Date?
private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

@IBOutlet weak var daysCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    daysCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "DayCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    let allDates = Helper.generateRandomDate(daysBack: 900, numberOf: 10)
    self.dates = allDates.sorted(by: {
        $0!.compare($1!) == .orderedAscending
    })
    startDate = self.dates.first! ?? Date()

    daysCollectionView.delegate = self
    daysCollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 900
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = daysCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell

    let cellDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: indexPath.item, to: self.startDate!)

    if let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath {
        cell.reloadCell(selectedRow == indexPath)
    } else {
        cell.reloadCell(false)
    }

    if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 15 {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
        let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: cellDate!)
        cell.drawMonth(month: monthString)
    }
    if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 1 && Calendar.current.component(.month, from: cellDate!) == 1 {
        print("drawYEAR")
        cell.drawYear(year:Calendar.current.component(.year, from: cellDate!))
    }
    if self.dates.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(cellDate!, inSameDayAs: $0!) }) {
        print("same")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
        print("not me")
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
    return cell
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.dates.count)))
    let randomDate = self.dates[randomIndex]
    let daysFrom = randomDate?.days(from: self.startDate!)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: daysFrom!, section: 0)
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    //daysCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    daysCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    daysCollectionView.reloadData()
}

}
```

`DayCollectionViewCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

class DayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var arrowImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

func drawMonth(month: String){

}
func drawYear(year: Int){

}

func reloadCell(_ isSelected:Bool){
    arrowImage.isHidden = !isSelected
}

}
```